# How can I make better use of all these information in the debugger?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, ide

if I have a simple code like below and I break after this line

`var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();`

I will see the variable `sheet` in the debugger. If I expand it, I will see many functions such as `getName`. If I expand `getName`,  I will see information such as `name: ""`.

I was expecting to see the name of the activeSheet but it was not there. What are these information for and how can I use them in debugging?

I just want to make sure there isn't a better way to debug and I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

`Sheet.getName` is a [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) object, and Google has chosen to not reveal the implementation of these methods. The [`name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name) of the function would contain the *function's* name rather than the name of the active sheet, but my recollection is that the V8 engine used by Google Apps Script does not reveal function names through that property in the debugger.

To see the sheet name in the debugger, declare another variable, like this:

```
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();
```